# Mapping to Realm Result to NSDictionary Error

Tags: ios, swift, casting, nsdictionary, realm

I have been using this extension to successfully map my Realm Results to NSDictionary:

```
extension Object {
func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
    let properties = self.objectSchema.properties.map { $0.name }
    let dictionary = self.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(properties)

    let mutabledic = NSMutableDictionary()
    mutabledic.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)

    for prop in self.objectSchema.properties as [Property]! {
        // find lists
        if let nestedObject = self[prop.name] as? Object {
            mutabledic.setValue(nestedObject.toDictionary(), forKey: prop.name)
        } else if let nestedListObject = self[prop.name] as? ListBase {
            var objects = [AnyObject]()
            for index in 0..<nestedListObject._rlmArray.count  {
                let object = nestedListObject._rlmArray[index] as AnyObject
                objects.append(object.toDictionary())
            }
            mutabledic.setObject(objects, forKey: prop.name)
        }
    }
    return mutabledic
}
}
```

But I am now trying to map :

```
let allObjectLists = realm.objects(UseItemList.self)
let firstObject  = allObjectLists[0].valueForKey("useItems")
let toDict = firstObject?.toDictionary() //error here
```

How do I fix this, there must be a way to map `allObjectLists[0].valueForKey("useItems")` to a Dictionary

Here is the Error I get:

```
2016-11-10 11:45:09.056 CPS Stocker[6187:167500] -[_TtGC10RealmSwift4ListC11CPS_Stocker7UseItem_ toDictionary]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa7f3a49650
2016-11-10 11:45:09.253 CPS Stocker[6187:167500] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtGC10RealmSwift4ListC11CPS_Stocker7UseItem_ toDictionary]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa7f3a49650'
```

And here is my `UseItemList` Object class:

```
class UseItemList: Object {
  dynamic var dateCreated = NSDate()
  dynamic var locationUnique = Int()
  dynamic var MainActivityReference1 = ""
  dynamic var MainActivityReference2 = ""
  let useItems = List<UseItem>() 
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the definition of `UseItemList`?

Comment: Also please share `UseItemList` class definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accessing an `Object` there.

That line of code `let firstObject  = allObjectLists[0].valueForKey("useItems")` is pulling out the `useItems` object, which is a `List` object. This is why it's reporting there's no method named `toDictionary()` available for it.

If you're trying to get the first object in `useItems` to generate a dictionary off that, it should be:

```
let allObjectLists = realm.objects(UseItemList.self) // Get all 'UseItemList' objects from Realm as a `Results` object
let firstObjectInList  = allObjectLists.first! // Get the first UseItemList object from the 'Results' object
let useItemsInFirstObject = firstObjectInList.useItems // Access the 'useItems' List object in the first object
let firstUseItem = useItems.first! // Access the first item from the 'useItems' List object
let toDict = firstItem.toDictionary() // Convert the first item into an array
```

Obviously you can condense this down into one line of code, but you need to make sure you're accessing all of the elements in the right order or else you won't get to a proper `Object` at the end. :)

Comment: No sorry you cannot call allObjectLists[0].valueForKey("useItems").first?.toDictionary() , because AnyObject has no member of "first". And by calling allObjectsLists[0] I already call the first item in the list.
let firstObjectDictionary  = allObjectLists[0].valueForKey("useItems").toDictionary() also gives the same error as my error

Comment: let firstObjectDictionary  = allObjectLists.valueForKey("useItems")![0].toDictionary()   gives me the same error too

Comment: Yeah, you're still not accessing an `Object` with that second line of code there. You're forgetting to get the first object from `allObjectLists`. In this case `allObjectLists` is an array, and `useItems` is an array. You need to make sure you're accessing their objects and not them directly, otherwise you'll get the error. I'll break up my answer into multiple steps.

Comment: This will work yes. But this is not what I want. I do not want the first Item in the `useItems` I want the first `useItems` in `UseItemList` to be converted to NSDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I fixed it :

```
let firstObjectInList  = allObjectLists.first! 
    let useItemsInFirstObject = firstObjectInList.useItems 

    for firstUseItem in useItemsInFirstObject {
        let dit = firstUseItem.toDictionary()
        usedObjectDictionaries.append(dit)

    }
```